# Build fails with OpenCV on cmake

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile a project using OpenCV 2.4 on ubuntu 16.04. I installed opencv using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
sudo apt-get install libopencv-nonfree-dev
```

However, when compiling the project I'm getting the following error message:

```
undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Ex)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c99")

message(STATUS "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS=${OpenCV_LIBS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(Ex ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(Ex ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set_property(TARGET Ex PROPERTY C_STANDARD 99)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Edit**

The output of the second message is

```
OpenCV_LIBS=opencv_videostab;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_nonfree;opencv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib3d
```

Comment: What is the output of your `message` commands? BTW, In the last line of the code you set *C* standard for the executable: it is useless, because executable is **C++**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've edited my question with the output. The C standard flags are neccessary because I have other source files in my project in C.

Comment: Library `opencv_imgproc`, which *should* implement given function, is in your list. Do you build the project with standard compiler (gcc)? `I have other source files in my project in C.` - But you apply "C" standard **only** for target which is compiled from single `.cpp` file.